# Высота слоя через Loader = 0. Как исправить

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick

Делаю вставку через Loader страницы qml. Но почему то высота rectLoader (Rectangle ), где лежит Loader равна 0 и следующий объект располагается от объекта который был до Loader-а.

Делаю привязку rectLoader к элементу до и после, но всё безуспешно. Наверно типичная ошибка новичка, подскажите пожалуйста как исправить.

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Flickable {
        id: flic
        anchors.fill: parent
        contentWidth: wrapper.width
        contentHeight: wrapper.height
        ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar { }
        ScrollBar.horizontal: ScrollBar { }

        Column {
            id: wrapper
            spacing: 20

            Rectangle {
                width: 300
                height: 300
                color: "blue"
            }
            Rectangle {
                id: rectB
                width: 300
                height: 300
                color: "black"
                MouseArea {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    onClicked: console.log(rectLoader.height)
                }
            }
            Rectangle {
                id: rectLoader
                anchors.top: rectB.bottom
                anchors.bottom: butB.top
                height: pageLoader.height
                Loader {
                    id: pageLoader
                    source: "Page1.qml"
                }
            }
            Button {
                id: butB
                //height: pageItem.height
                text: "Закрыть"
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Page1.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.7

Item {
    id: pageItem
    height: pageColumn.height
    Column {
        id: pageColumn
        spacing: 30
        Text {
            text: "111"
            font.pointSize: 20
        }
        Rectangle {
            width: 100
            height: 400
            color: "green"
        }
        Rectangle {
            width: 100
            height: 400
            color: "red"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Решение: вынести Loader из ректангла:

```
    import QtQuick 2.7
    import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
    import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0

    ApplicationWindow {
        visible: true
        width: 640
        height: 480
        title: qsTr("Hello World")

        Flickable {
            id: flic
            anchors.fill: parent
            contentHeight: wrapper.height
            ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar { }
            ScrollBar.horizontal: ScrollBar { }

            Column {
                id: wrapper
                spacing: 20
                width: flic.width

                Rectangle {
                    width: 300
                    height: 300
                    color: "blue"
                }
                Rectangle {
                    id: rectB
                    width: 300
                    height: 300
                    color: "black"
                    MouseArea {
                        anchors.fill: parent
                        onClicked: console.log(rectLoader.height)
                    }
                }
                Loader {
                    id: pageLoader
                    source: "Page1.qml"
                }
                Button {
                    id: butB
                    text: "Закрыть"
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Page1.qml

```
    import QtQuick 2.7

    Column {
        id: pageColumn
        spacing: 30
        Text {
            text: "111"
            font.pointSize: 20
        }
        Rectangle {
            width: 100
            height: 400
            color: "green"
        }
        Rectangle {
            width: 100
            height: 400
            color: "red"
        }
    }
```